# Error al ejecutar App

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una app desarrollada en `AndroidStudio` para agregar unas actividades pero al tratar de ejecutar tengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase que tiene el problema es de Material Design, lo que debes asegurar es tener especificado como minimo la API 21 en tu proyecto.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    ...
    }
```

y

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

revisa el documento **[Mantener la compatibilidad](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html?hl=es)** de la documentación.

Comment: Ok...voy hacer eso y te comento EleNaSys

Comment: Realizalo y comenta los resultados. :)

Comment: Elenasys para eso debo entrar al SDK manager e instalar Android 5.0 o existe alguna forma de agregarla a mi proyecto directamente??

Comment: Ups, si no lo tienes instalado debes realizarlo!, realizalo dese el SDK manager.

Comment: Si...estoy en eso

Comment: Resolvi los errores Instale Android 7.0

Comment: compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

Comment: Usando Android Studio con buildToolsVersion 23 es suficiente pero cuando actualizas te instala la última versiòn, en este caso 24.